# An already sucessfully pushed commit keeps showing it needs to be pushed

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a situation where, on my one PC, using Sourcetree an already successfully pushed commit continuously keeps displaying a "3", wanting to push the commit which is already visible on the Git web interface.  No errors were shown, and every time I push, it seems to be happy for a while, and then the "3" appears again, without actually making any changes.

I think however the error is on the server side, because, on my other PC, also using Sourcetree, when I fetch, the commit appears, but as soon as I want to pull, it simply disappears and I remain on the commit I was last.  This happens even if I switch to another branch and try to update the branch in question.  Fetching fetches it, but trying to update it to the latest commit, the "fetched commit" simply disappears and that branch remains on the commit it was before.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: What if you use the command line?

Comment: Also you don't by any chance have two remotes?

Comment: Could you please clarify some points ? here is a list : 1. Where is your remote hosted ? one of the web hosted git services (github, gitlab, ...) or on a private server ? 2. do you know of any automated task on your machine/your remote, that could somehow change your repo (e.g : autofecth every 15 seconds, autoformatting ...) ? 3. Is your local repo/remote repo on a shared drive, or a synced directory (Dropbox, Onedrive, Nextcloud ...) ?

Comment: Thanks guys.  This is hosted on github.  I indeed did have two remotes.  Somehow capitalization messed things up.  Fetching didn't seem to care about it, but pulling did.  Will post answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

So it turns out somehow capitalization got mixed up.  Forcing a push to `testing` instead of `Testing` fixed it.  My local repo from where I made the push is still `Testing` now, but it pushes to `testing` on the remote.  The other machine keeps pulling from `testing` as it has and now also has the complete commit flow.

What is really strange is that fetching it on the other machine seems to discard capitalization differences, but once I pull it, it gets picky.  Well, that and, I have no idea how this happened.

Comment: Sourcetree has its own layer of software atop Git, which could make things worse, but in general, it works like this: Git itself thinks case (upper vs lower) *matters*. So branches X and x are different. *But*, Git stores branch (and remote-tracking) names using *file names* now and then. If your *OS* thinks case *doesn't* matter, suddenly branches X and x are *the same* branch. So these are the same branch, except when they're not, which is when they're strings stored *in* files instead of strings stored *as* file-names.

Comment: This leads to a general rule: if you ever use computers on which file names are *not* case sensitive—where you can't have both README and ReadMe in the same directory—DO NOT mix upper and lower case. Or, more generally, make all branch and remote names in lower case only.